# What is the difference between #[test] and #[cfg(test)] in Rust?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, rust, rust-cargo

The [Rust docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/attributes/testing.html) mention that the `#[test]` directive is for marking a function which is only compiled and executed in test mode. What is the reason for having the `#[cfg(test)]` directive then?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`#[cfg(test)]`, like any other [`#[cfg]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html#the-cfg-attribute), can be applied to any piece of code (constant, module, function, statement...) and filters it out from compilation when not compiling tests. `#[test]` applies only to functions, and in addition to removing the function when not compiling tests, it also registers it as a unit test.

You can use `#[cfg(test)]` for example to not compile the whole module of the tests (to save compilation time), or to not compile test-only code such as test helpers or other testing logic in the crate.

Answer (score 2):

`#[cfg(test)]` tells the Rust compiler that the following code should only be compiled when the test configuration is active.

`#[test]` tells the Rust compiler that the following code should only be compiled when the test configuration is active **and that the following function is a test**.

E.g. you might have a helper function `test_helper` inside `mod tests` that does not test anything and should not be considered as a seperate test. So you want it to compile only for testing but not to be run as separate test by `cargo test`.